# Neo4j: fulltext indices and auto indexing in Cypher

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I'm currently struggeling  with fulltext indices and auto indexing in Cypher.

I'm using Java embedded, Neo4j v 1.8.2.

My basic question is: How can fulltext indices  be queried with Cypher?

When I create the following index:

```
Index<Node> fulltextIndex = index.forNodes( "fulltextIndex",
            MapUtil.stringMap( IndexManager.PROVIDER, "lucene",
            "type", "fulltext" ) );
```

The following Cypher statement does not return anything:

```
START n=node:fulltextIndex(name='*er*') RETURN n;
```

The following piece of java code returns the desired node though:

```
Node found = fulltextIndex.query("name", "*er*").getSingle();
id= found.getId();
String cypherQuery="START n=node("+id+") RETURN n";
```

So where's actually the difference? Why does the Cypher statement not work?

Also I'd like to if there's any way to combine fulltext indexing with auto indexing? The following (as seen on http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/auto-indexing.html) does not seem to work:

```
Index<Node> fulltextIndex = index.forNodes("node_auto_index", "fulltextIndex",
            MapUtil.stringMap( IndexManager.PROVIDER, "lucene",
            "type", "fulltext" ) );
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Try the following Cypher statement as your Lucene query seems to be wrong:

```
START n=node:fulltextIndex("name:*er*") RETURN n;
```

Comment: Do the quotes go around the whole property-value pair? Normally they are only wrapped around the property, right?
Anyway, I tried the following (in java embedded):

String query="START n=node:fulltextIndex (\“name=*er*\“) RETURN n"; 
String query="START n=node:fulltextIndex ('name=*er*') RETURN n"; 

Both result in a NullPointerException

Comment: Oh, that was easy! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: About time this was accepted as the answer I think.