# Spring Data Neo4j - Fulltext Index in Cypher query

Tags: java, spring, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, full-text-indexing

I access fulltext index by the **findAllByQuery()** repository method, it works fine, but i cannot pass pagination params, so i'm trying Cypher query which can use **LIMIT**, below are my testings:

Case 1 - **Works fine but hardcoding**

```
@Query( "START n=node:searchName('name:*test*') return n" )
EndResult<SomeGraphObject> findByName()
```

Case 2(**Never work**), give **term = "*test*"**, throw exception

```
@Query( "START n=node:searchName('name:{0}') return n" )
EndResult<SomeGraphObject> findByName(String term)
```

Case 3(**Partially working**) - Works fine when give **luceneExpression = "name:*test*"**, but doesn't work when give **luceneExpression = "name:*test test*"**, i mean doesn't work when query string include  space.

```
@Query( "START n=node:searchName({0}) return n" )
EndResult<SomeGraphObject> findByName(String luceneExpression)
```

Another issue is when i use **findAllByQuery() repository method**, index **searchName** will be created when first time **create or query**. But when i use Cypher query without creating index **searchName**, it will throw "Index **searchName** does not exist" error.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

SomeGraphObject.java

```
@NodeEntity
public class SomeGraphObject {

    @GraphId Long id;

    @Indexed(indexName="searchName", indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT)
    String name;

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026027/neo4j-fulltext-indices-and-auto-indexing-in-cypher

Comment: Hi Eugeny, thanks for the reply, but this link only answer case 1 which is already working, the problem is hardcoding.

Comment: Can you try  `luceneExpression = "name:\`*test test*\`"` ?

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic query expression you should only use the case 3  code.
The reason space is not working, is because in Lucene space means another expression, but for some reason neo4j demands the field name in front of any expression meaning you should either use:
    `name:*test name:test*`
    `name:(*test test*)`

BTW I think that a query that begins with a '*' is illegal in Lucene, so it's kinda odd it works.